# Javascript - Load function if external script takes time to load

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have added async for the script tag and the code looks as follows ;

```
(function(){
    var jsfile=document.createElement('script');
    jsfile.type='text/javascript';
    jsfile.src="http://t01.proximic.com/c.js?m=1&"+e.replace(/\'/g,"")+"&k="+Math.random();
    jsfile.async = true;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsfile);

    function loadpage() {
        console.log("pageloaded");
    }

    if(window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load",loadpage,false);
    else if(window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload",loadpage);
    else 
    window.onload=loadpage;
})();
```

Wanted to know if the script takes time to load suppose more than 2 mins than will the onload event not fire untill the script is loaded.I have given async to the script tag.If no how can i get onload event to fire though the js file in script tag has not finished loading.

Please help.

Comment: You can test it yourself: Put a `console.log('func_name: ', new Date)` to `loadpage` and your asynch script. Then you'll find out, when they are executed.